# Is there a universal way to organize spacing html?

Tags: html

I've looked both online and on stack
overflow but I haven't found any concrete
answer. I'd like to keep things organized
and correct.

```
When I look at websites and use dev tools 
to dissect pages it seems hard to really 
distinguish the appropriate spacing, if 
you know of any reference that explains 
that'd be awesome.


Also does, vs code have an extension or 
shortcut that does this for you?

Exaggerated Example:
```

```html
  

     <html>
<header>
       <How do i know when to tab out
<And when to tab in>
                <body>

Thank you for your time. Have a great day!
```

Comment: I still don't get it what exactly is your prob?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is regarding code indentation

There are no hard and fast rules - some prefer tabs to space and others prefer spaces (usually 2 or 4). The only important thing is to keep it consistent - choose one approach and stick with it.

in termas of code indentation its actually very simple - if something is a child of something else - it gets indented relative to that parent.

As a general rule try to prevent excessive nesting - sometimes it is better to pull out a level or two - but  as a guide - here is a basic page skeleton with what I consider to be basic and acceptable spacing (indentation ) - note that there is a splash of Bootstrap in there to demonstrate indentation of realistic content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Label text"</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code skeleton sourced from (https://gist.github.com/taniarascia/d0308ff82a1d4344a904) and modified to suit.

Also note that the above is good for reading in the dev environtment - but is often minimised to remove whitepsace in production environments. But when you are learning to code - one of the best habits to get into is to follow an indentation guideline - it helps code readability, chunkingg into smaller portions and allows easier recognition of when you have missed a closing tag.

Comment: Code indentation, that's the word I was looking for! Lol. Your answer was extremely helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it was helpful - if it resolves the isue - please check the "Accepted" checkbox so that other devs know that the isesue has been resolved. Thanks and happy coding :)